# VIM no comma in insert mode

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu-12.04

I have seen other questions in this topic but none of them were useful. My vimrc is just like a default vimrc when u install it using apt-get install vim. I even tried a fresh install of vim but no luck! It's just that comma key doesn't work in insert mode in VIM. I can type a comma using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> , but not the normal way. (by pressing comma character). There are no set cinkeys or any mapping in my vimrc! The result of running commands such as imap or map are
    no mapping found

Comment: start vim with `vim -u NONE` and try it again

Comment: Yeah that works :D What should I do to make it does this automatically without having to type vim -u NONE